# How to auto-recover after unclean shutdown?

Tags: boot, fsck, xfs, corruption

I have an embedded system that I do not have very easy access to. Although in retrospect, I shouldn't have built it this way, but the only way to shut down the system is to kill power. This works 99.9% of the time, but every once in a while, I get the following error on boot:

```
failed to mount XXXX.  Wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock.
```

and I need to run `xfs_repair` on it to proceed.

In an ideal world (moving forward), I would have a system that automatically detects a failure like this an auto-repairs it, but at a minimum, I'd like to be able to continue boot, or allow ssh remote access to fix.

I'm trying to figure out how `fsck` plays into all of this, or if it's unrelated. As in, is this failure due to a latent error in the system (caused by multiple unclean shutdowns) that was running fine until `fsck` finally caught it and halted boot in the process, or is this a failure that could have been caught and fixed by `fsck`?

Basically, I'm wondering if intentionally skipping `fsck` on boot will allow the system to continue booting (at risk), or if I should force `fsck` to run at boot every time to catch and fix errors like this? I just want a system that can handle unclean shutdowns and continue to boot, even if that means loss of recent data.

Comment: Fsck is meant to detect and (optionally) repair inconsistent filesystems and it is normally done in case of boot after power outage. Fsck ensures the fs is in consistent state before it is mounted. Any major linux distro can do fsck with auto-repair.
It may be some specific setting in your embedded system OS that influences this behavior. Each distro has its own way of configuring that, but you can also specify parameters on the kernel boot line. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1007323/147942 , for example.

Comment: Be carefull that fsck.xfs (as your system in with xfs FS) doesn't repair anything except if you force it to run xfs_repair by tweeking boot cmdline (fsck.mode=force). It can be seen here https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsck.xfs.8.html

Comment: Simply run `sync` before killing power. Or even twice for good measure. In absolute most cases FS damage is down to "dirty" unflushed buffers this command deals with.

Comment: @admstg would this force xfs_repair to run every time the system starts (since xfs always runs after unclean shutdown), or just as required? If every time, this sounds like it would take a while, no? Alternatively, what is the downside to having fsck never run? would the system boot even with the inconsistencies?

Comment: Yes, it will run at each reboot but should be fast if the Filesystem is clean. Well if xfs_repair don't run at boot you will probably be in the same situation if it's corrupted. Probably a sync (or even sync;sync) will be enough as a first attempt.

Comment: @admstg So it's not just fsck finding an inconsistency and haulting the mount/boot, it's an actual corruption that would be caught regardless of whether or not fsck is run or not? I'm stuck between telling fsck to never run, or telling it to always run xfs_repair